# no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"

Tags: r, rvest

I'm new here. I wanted to check working my old R script (from april 2021) and I know, that it not working now. I looked for solve in the Internet, upgraded my R language and needed libraries and it still not working. In april 2021 everything working good, without problems.

This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

{
  cleaning = function()
      {
      file_html <<- read_html("https://www.nbp.pl/homen.aspx?f=/kursy/RatesA.html", 
                              encoding = "UTF-8")
      
      table_html <<- html_node(file_html, ".pad5")
      
      table_r <<- html_table(table_html, fill = TRUE, dec = ",")
      
      currencies <<- data.frame(table_r)
      
      colnames(currencies) <<- c("currency_name", "currency_code", "mid_rate")
      }
  cleaning()
}
```

After run this code I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("html_table") : 
  no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that call `html_node(file_html, ".pad5")` returns a missing element, because there is no element of id `.pad5` at the website. They probably have changed names of the elements, if you claim that it used to work.

Comment: Ok, thank you, everything working. I changed attribiute `".pad5"` to `"table.nbptable"`, because they really have changed names of elements on website.